# What is the legal bat size in international cricket?

Tags: cricket

There is any specific bat size? Which is used in International Cricket.If yes then is it  depend on player height?

Answer (score 1):

The 2017 update to the Laws[5] saw no changes to the maximum length of the bat, which is still 38 inches/96.52 cm, but a new specification stated that the edge of the bat cannot be more than 1.56 inches / 4cm while the depth cannot be more than 2.64 inches / 6.7cm.
The umpires are now given a bat gauge so they can check the legality of the bat at any time.